# Create new column with Pandas .apply() even if DataFrame is empty

Tags: python, pandas, database

I want to use Pandas apply to create a new column, and I want this functionality to be fail-save even if that DataFrame is empty. Here is a minimal example that works as expected:

```
df      = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]), columns=['a','b']) # two columns
add     = lambda x: x['a'] + x['b'] # add column a and b # add two values
df['c'] = df.apply( add, axis=1 ) # creates new column c, as anticipated
```

However, it gets problematic when df happens to be empty. Consider the following example where now the DataFrame is empty, but otherwise equal:

```
df      = pd.DataFrame( columns=['a','b']) # two columns, but no values
df['c'] = df.apply( add, axis=1 ) # raises an error!
```

How can I execute this last column safely, such that it just appends a column 'c' to the DataFrame, even if df is empty?

Interestingly enough, this works

```
df.apply( add, axis=1 )
```

but cannot be appended as column 'c'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [calling apply() on an empty pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990182/calling-apply-on-an-empty-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a new column `c` based on the sum of columns `a` and `b`, then you can just do the following:

```py
df['c'] = df['a'] + df['b']  # creates new column c, as anticipated :)
```

That way, you don't need to assign a lambda expression to a function `add`, (it is not recommended to assign lambda expressions a function).

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), columns=['a', 'b'])  # two columns
print(df)
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4

df['c'] = df['a'] + df['b']  # creates new column c, as anticipated
print(df)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  3  4  7

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b'])  # two columns, but no values
df['c'] = df['a'] + df['b']  # creates new column c, as anticipated
print(df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
```

Even if the dataframe is empty, above method will work.

Comment: Granted, for my simple example this is indeed a solution. But My question applies more generally, where "add" is a complicated function that relies on other components and cannot be serialized like in the "add" example.

Answer (score 0):

If one axis (rows or columns) is empty then the apply function returns an [empty result](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2e218d10984e9919f0296931d92ea851c6a6faf5/pandas/core/apply.py#L758).

Your defined lambda function returns a [pandas.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html). For handling empty [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) it is necessary to be more explicit on the result type of the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method and use the `reduce` mode.

> ‘reduce’ : returns a Series if possible rather than expanding list-like results. This is the opposite of ‘expand’.

This will work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'])
df['c'] = df.apply(add, axis=1, result_type='reduce')
```